# Ruby on rails. Update different models from one link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, hidden-field, update-attributes

I need to change the attributes of two different models at the same time. I have a `gig` model. gig `has_many` `requests`
I have a form to change the status of the `gig` to `filled`, and at the same time I want to change the status of that gigs' requests to 'reject'. (The ones that don't already ahve a status of 'hired')

Request has `status: string`

Gig has `filled: boolean`

Request model:

```
scope :nothired, -> { where.not(status: 'hired') }
```

Request controller:

```
def reject
  @request = Request.find(params[:id])
      @request.update(status: "reject")
      @request.save
      UserMailer.reject_notification(@request).deliver
      redirect_to gig_requests_path
      flash[:notice] = "MARKED AS REJECTED"
end
```

view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @gig, :method => "put" do |t| %>
<% @gig.requests.nothired.each do |request| %>
<%= t.hidden_field :filled, :value => true %>

<%= t.submit t('dash.filltitle'), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "fill-gig-btn"  %>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now i'm not sure how to format this to include the `requests` controller action.

I have tried passing the `requests reject` action through a hidden field (the reject action is in the controller and it works) with:

```
 <%= t.hidden_field { controller: "requests", action: "reject", id: request.id }, method: :post %>
```

But this gives:

```
undefined method `{:url=>{:action=>"reject", :controller=>"requests", :id=>53}, :method=>:post}' for #<Gig:0x0055ef27d98cc8>
```

Any advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this within the Gig controller.

So within gig#update action, you can set all of the child requests to 'reject' with something like this:

```
@gig.requests.each do |request|
  request.update_attributes(status: 'reject')
end
```

You want to make sure this only fires if @gig was updated successfully.

Because of that, it might be more elegant to handle this from your Gig model using [callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)

Comment: I had thought of that but the 'reject' action in the requests controller is set up to email each user that created a request. Updating the status like this wouldn't trigger that action.

Comment: I see. Again, perhaps you should be leaning harder on callbacks to send out those emails and taking all that code out of the controller? You could try putting the emails on an `after_update` inside `Request` model?